# Eclipseのエディタ画面でタブにファイル名が表示されない

Tags: eclipse

EclipseのOxygenを使っています。

通常、新しいクラスを作成したりソースコードを開くとエディタ上部のタブ？にファイル名が表示されると思うのですが、外観を変えただけで表示されなくなってしまいました。

どうすれば元に戻せるでしょうか？

ちなみに以前の外観に戻してもダメです。右クリックで「閉じる」だけはできます。

Answer (score 0):

すいません。再起動することで修復→自己解決に至りました。回答を検討くださった方々、大変失礼致しました。